# Modificar valor de una variable dentro de un list comprehension

Tags: python, lista, bucle-for, variables

Os pongo un poco en situación.
Hay un ejercicio básico que trata de ingresar un monto y el programa te desglosa el cambio (1 billete de 50, 1 de 10, una moneda de 2 etc etc)

En mi ímpetu por simplificar el código intente hacerlo con list comprehension pero me encontré con varios obstáculos.

Para empezar el tema de la variable en la que se guarda el monto restante. Por ejemplo: Si el monto es de 156 se restarían 3 billetes de 50 y sobrarían 6, la siguiente iteración seria con el billete de 20, pero como no se variar dentro de la línea de código del list comprehension el valor del monto para dejar el monto restante, en la siguiente iteración vuelve a hacerla con el monto inicial (156)

Experimentando y practicando pude hacer el programita con la lógica en una sola línea de código, aunque claro, se que hice trampas ya que pude dar dos instrucciones usando los corchetes del format de un string.

Hacerlo lo hice, pero me justaría que me dijerais si se puede variar el valor de una variable dentro de una operación.

También me gustaría saber como lo hubierais hecho vosotros, con o sin trampa, el caso es que la lógica esté en una sola línea de código tipo list comprehension.

Gracias y espero vuestras respuestas. Aquí os dejo como lo hice yo:

```
monto=float(input('¿Cuanto quiere que le cambie? '))
billetes = [50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01]
cambiado , resultado = [] , []
    
[resultado.append((f'Billetes de {billete}: {int((monto-sum(cambiado))/billete)} {cambiado.append(int((monto-sum(cambiado))/billete)*billete)}').replace(' None','')) for billete in billetes if monto >= billete]

print(resultado,'\n')
print(cambiado)
```

y este es el resultado de 283.48:

> ['Billetes de 50: 5', 'Billetes de 20: 1', 'Billetes de 10: 1',
> 'Billetes de 5: 0', 'Billetes de 2: 1', 'Billetes de 1: 1', 'Billetes
> de 0.5: 0', 'Billetes de 0.2: 2', 'Billetes de 0.1: 0', 'Billetes de
> 0.05: 1', 'Billetes de 0.02: 1', 'Billetes de 0.01: 1']
>
> [250, 20, 10, 0, 2, 1, 0.0, 0.4, 0.0, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01]

POST EDICION

Lo conseguí hacer de una forma mas simple de esta manera gracias al operador Walrus, esta vez no hay trampas (creo jeje):

```
monto = float(input('¿Cuanto quiere que le cambie? '))
billetes = [50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01]
[f' billetes de {billete}:   {( monto - (monto := monto - ( int(monto/billete) *billete )) )/billete}'  for billete in billetes]
```

Dando como resultado:

> [' billetes de 50:   2.0',  ' billetes de 20:   2.0',  ' billetes de
> 10:   0.0',  ' billetes de 5:   0.0',  ' billetes de 2:   1.0',  '
> billetes de 1:   1.0',  ' billetes de 0.5:   1.0',  ' billetes de 0.2:
> 1.0',  ' billetes de 0.1:   0.0',  ' billetes de 0.05:   1.0',  ' billetes de 0.02:   1.0',  ' billetes de 0.01:   1.0']

Si alguien tiene una forma mejor, please, me encantaría leerlo.

Gracias

Comment: Se puede hacer, probablemente. No es buena idea, definitivamente.

Comment: Buenas Candid, lo conseguí usando el operador warlug, edito el post para que se vea el resultado

Answer (score 1):

Toda sintaxis es susceptible de ser abusada :-)

La razón de existir de las list-comprehensions es hacer el código más legible. Muchos bucles simples se vuelven más legibles al escribirlos en forma de list-comprehension. Otros en cambio se vuelven más ilegibles. En este segundo caso, no veo ninguna razón para no usar un bucle "normal". La eficiencia será la misma, si es eso lo que te preocupa.

Dicho esto.

Yo habría usado `divmod()`, que es una función que en un solo paso te devuelve el cociente y el resto de una división, evitándote tener que hacer restas y multiplicaciones. En este caso, por ejemplo, `divmod(monto, billete)` te daría a la vez el número de billetes de ese valor necesarios, y el resto (que sería el monto para la iteración siguiente).

De este modo, en forma de bucle "normal" quedará así:

```
monto = 283.48
for billete in billetes:
    n, monto = divmod(monto, billete)
    print(f"Billetes de {billete}: {n}")
```

Resultado:

```
Billetes de 50: 5.0
Billetes de 20: 1.0
Billetes de 10: 1.0
Billetes de 5: 0.0
Billetes de 2: 1.0
Billetes de 1: 1.0
Billetes de 0.5: 0.0
Billetes de 0.2: 2.0
Billetes de 0.1: 0.0
Billetes de 0.05: 1.0
Billetes de 0.02: 1.0
Billetes de 0.01: 1.0
```

Francamente, dudo que pueda dejarse más legible y compacto que esto.

### Y ahora el horror

Si insistimos en escribirlo en forma de comprehension, solo como diversión (ya que la legibilidad es abismal), yo crearía un diccionario en vez de una lista. Las claves del diccionario serían los tipos de billete, y los valores del diccionario serían el número de billetes de ese tipo.

Si queremos usar el mismo truco de `divmod()`, el problema es que el operador walrus no deja "desempaquetar tuplas" (que es lo que hacía en la línea `n, monto = divmod()`), por lo que hay que recoger la tupla devuelta por `divmod()` en una sola variable para acceder separadamente a sus elementos [0] (la división entera) y [1] (el resto de la división).

Eso da lugar al siguiente **engendro**:

```py
monto = 283.48
r = {billete: (aux:=divmod(monto, billete), monto:=aux[1])[0][0] for billete in billetes}
print(r)
```

Resultado:

```
{50: 5.0, 20: 1.0, 10: 1.0, 5: 0.0, 2: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 0.5: 0.0, 0.2: 2.0, 0.1: 0.0, 0.05: 1.0, 0.02: 1.0, 0.01: 1.0}
```

**Nota**. El `[0][0]` es otro truco horrible. Ya que no podemos poner `monto` a la izquierda de `divmod`, me veo obligado a meter otra "sentencia" dentro de la expresión, que es `, monto:=aux[1]`. Pero Python no permite meter varias sentencias dentro de una expresión, de modo que abuso de la coma para ello, con lo que en realidad estoy creando una tupla de dos elementos. El primer elemento es `aux:=divmod(monto, billete)` y el segundo es `monto:=aux[1]`. Por ello todo eso va entre paréntesis y finalmente el `[0]` me permite acceder al primer elemento de esta tupla, que es el valor de `aux`, y el segundo  `[0]` me permite acceder al primer elemento dentro de `aux`, que es el cociente entero devuelto por `divmod()`.

Comment: Hay que saber cuando conviene mas una comprension de lista o un for normal. Si no necesitas construir un iterable (como cadenas, listas, diccionarios o generadores) entonces una comprension ocuparia eficiencia al cohete creando, por ejemplo, una lista llena de None.

Comment: Me ha encantado, muchisimas gracias. aprendi lo del divmod (una buena herramienta). Basicamente lo que queria era ver si lo podia conseguir. Pero acabas de abrirme un mundo nuevo. Muchas gracias de nuevo